# How to separate Docpad system from content

Tags: javascript, node.js, docpad

I need to separate the Docpad system from the actual content that gets rendered. The Docpad system is a Node module that gets npm installed inside the content project.

Here's the structure of content project:

```
content-project/
  - src/
    - documents/
    - files/
    - layout/
  - node_modules/
    - docpad-system/
      - node_modules/
        - docpad/
        - docpad-plugins-*/
      - docpad.js
      - package.json
```

Is this the proper way to structure this project so that the docpad system is separate from the content?

I'm not sure if the docpad config is on the right place. I tried setting the srcPath and rootPath but the contents doesn't render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. But if you just want to change the location of the `src` and `out` folder then changing the `srcPath` and `outPath` in the docpad.coffee/js should be all you need to do. Like this:

```
// Out Path
// Where should we put our generated website files?
// If it is a relative path, it will have the resolved `rootPath` prepended to it
outPath: '../out',  // default out

// Src Path
// Where can we find our source website files?
// If it is a relative path, it will have the resolved `rootPath` prepended to it
srcPath: '../src',  // default src
```

This will force Docpad to look for the source files in the folder above the `rootPath` and also output the rendered files in the same place (and within the 'out' folder).

As a result you might have a project structure something like this:

```
content-project/
    docpad-system
    src
    out
```

docpad-system would contain all your node modules and docpad.coffee/js and package.json. This would be the root of your project as far as docpad was concerned and this is where you would want to run docpad from.